# How to fix error to fit model but,y_train gives error as value error in ML?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, decision-tree

How to fix error when i am trying to run at time of y_train it giving valuerror.I am checked the shape of y_test,y_train it gives one value (2000,) but another not gives.What can do so that the error fixes.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('iris.csv')
df.head()
df.shape
df.loc[df["species"] == "setosa", "species"] = 0
df.loc[df["species"] == "versicolor", "species"] = 1
df.loc[df["species"] == "virginica", "species"] = 2
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X=df.drop('species',axis=1)
y=df['species']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,test_size=0.2, random_state=156)
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
my_model = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0)
result = my_model.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Comment: Can you share the whole Traceback?

Comment: can u share the stack trace

Comment: I am using google colab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you do:

```
df.loc[df["species"] == "setosa", "species"] = 0
df.loc[df["species"] == "versicolor", "species"] = 1
df.loc[df["species"] == "virginica", "species"] = 2
```

makes `df['species']` an `object` dtype, which is not supported by `DecisionTreeClassifier`. Instead, you should do:

```
df['species'] = df['species'].map({'setosa':0, 'versicolor':1, 'virginica':2})
```